# ServiceStack response after a successful authentication throws error. what is missing?

Tags: servicestack

I used a restconsole to post:

```
http://MyApp/auth/credentials
```

My Custom AuthProvider below:

```
 public class MyAppCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{

    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,
    string userName, string password)
    {         
        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        //Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false

        SetUp();

        var userDao = _appHost.Container.Resolve<IUserDao>();
        bool isValid = false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return false;

        var user = userDao.GetUserByUsername(userName);

        if (user == null)
            return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
            return false;

        if (CheckPassword(password, user.Password))
        {
            bool isApproved = user.IsApproved;
            if (isApproved && user.Status == (short)Status.Active)
            {
                isValid = true;
                user.IsOnLine = true;
                user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                userDao.Update(user);
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService,
        IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens,
        Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            // Authenticate the user.
            var userRepo = authService.TryResolve<IUserDao>();
            var user = userRepo.GetUserByUsername(session.UserAuthName);

            session.LastName = user.Lastname;
            session.UserName = user.Username;
            session.Email = user.UserEmail;
            session.DisplayName = user.Lastname + " " + user.Othernames;
            session.IsAuthenticated = true;

            //Important: You need to save the session!
            SessionExpiry = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            // log error
        }

    }


    public void SetUp()
    {
        _appHost = new BasicAppHost().Init();
        var container = _appHost.Container;

        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyAppDB"].ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<UserDao, IUserDao>();            
    }
    }
```

After execution exists public override void OnAuthenticated(...)

I get the error below:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.HandleException(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName, Exception ex) +206
   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName) +1058
   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +264
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

What params or configuration or step am i missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try debugging your code more first. Try to find out what line/object is throwing the NullReferenceException. Try to comment out your custom code and just return true or false, see if the problem goes away. Isolating the problem code is the key to finding the problem.

Comment: Hi Raul, thanks for the tip, the issue is with the custom code, authentication worked fine after commenting out the custom code. will fix that.